# notes at the end of the table

Tags: tables, notes

I want to add some tiny notes to the following table but its coming out of the lines.

```
\begin{table}[H] 
\centering
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.65}

    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
    \hline
    Variable& Min & 1st Qu. & Median & Mean & 3rd Qu. & Max \\ \hline
        loan amnt & 500 & 8000 & 13000 & 14760 & 20000 & 35000\\
        int rate & 0.0532 & 0.0999& 0.1299 & 0.1324 & 0.1620 & 0.2899\\
        credit grade & 1.00 & 4.00 & 5.00 & 5.203 & 6.00 & 7.00 \\
        sub grade1 & 1.00 & 7.00 & 11.00 & 11.95 & 16.00 & 35.00 \\

        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\tiny Notes: Credit Grade is the grade assigned by the Lending Club based on the FICOrano credit rating information along with other information. Credit Grade ‘1’ is the loan category of ....} \\

    \caption{Descriptive statistics for some of the variables}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `\multicolumn` must be inside the `tabular` environment.

Comment: @dexteritas if I do that the last column of the table will be as long as the text. I want the text to fit the length of the last line of the table

Comment: Why not use a `threeparttable` for this?

Comment: @marmot thanks. but how I can expand the notes till the end of the table. right now goes till the middle of the table and skips to the next line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `threeparttable`. Here's a possible code, but do you really want that result?

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{threeparttable, array, float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.65}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{*{7}{l}}
    \hline
    Variable& Min & 1st Qu. & Median & Mean & 3rd Qu. & Max \\ \hline
        loan amnt & 500 & 8000 & 13000 & 14760 & 20000 & 35000\\
        int rate & 0.0532 & 0.0999& 0.1299 & 0.1324 & 0.1620 & 0.2899\\
        credit grade & 1.00 & 4.00 & 5.00 & 5.203 & 6.00 & 7.00 \\
        sub grade1 & 1.00 & 7.00 & 11.00 & 11.95 & 16.00 & 35.00 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}[online, flushleft]
  \tiny
   \item[]Notes: Credit Grade is the grade assigned by the Lending Club based on the FICOrano credit rating information along with other information. Credit Grade ‘1’ is the loan category of ....
  \end{tablenotes}
    \caption{Descriptive statistics for some of the variables}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suggest using this code, which results in a nicer table, in my opinion (load `booktabs`):

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{*{7}{l}}
        \toprule[1.2pt]
        Variable& Min & 1st Qu. & Median & Mean & 3rd Qu. & Max \\ 
        \cmidrule[0.8pt](lr){1-7}
            loan amnt & 500 & 8000 & 13000 & 14760 & 20000 & 35000\\
            int rate & 0.0532 & 0.0999& 0.1299 & 0.1324 & 0.1620 & 0.2899\\
            credit grade & 1.00 & 4.00 & 5.00 & 5.203 & 6.00 & 7.00 \\
            sub grade1 & 1.00 & 7.00 & 11.00 & 11.95 & 16.00 & 35.00 \\
            \midrule[1.2pt]
        \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}[online, flushleft]
      \footnotesize%\smallskip
       \item[]\hspace*{-\fontdimen2\font}Notes: Credit Grade is the grade assigned by the Lending Club based on the FICOrano credit rating information along with other information. Credit Grade ‘1’ is the loan category of ....
      \end{tablenotes}
        \caption{Descriptive statistics for some of the variables}
        \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MWE using `\multicolumn{3}{|p{10cm}|}{...}` to enable linebreak.
You can adjust the width as you like.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    foo & bar & foobar\\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{10cm}|}{\tiny Notes: Credit Grade is the grade assigned by the Lending Club based on the FICOrano credit rating information along with other information. Credit Grade ‘1’ is the loan category of ....}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]